# How to get notified about imageWithContentsOfFile: completion?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, delegates, uiimage

I load a huge-huge image with imageWithContentsOfFile:, so I have to set up an activityIndicator during the process.

Is there any way/any delegate callback I can use to be informed about the end of this loading process?

Comment: Was there any resolution to this question?

Answer (score 3):

`imageWithContentsOfFile` is synchronous.

You could start an activity indicator, load your big image into memory in a background thread and then go back to the main thread and stop the indicator.

```
- (void)loadBigImage {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadBigImageInBackground) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)loadBigImageInBackground {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"..."];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(bigImageLoaded:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)bigImageLoaded:(UIImage *)img {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Nope. sorry!

Long answer :

You could open the file in a background process (an NSOperation?) bit by bit using C style methods i.e. fopen, fread etc) and fire notifications back to the main thread during the load. Then create the image and fire a notification that the image is ready?

Comment: Any other image loading method in a bit more Obejctive-C/UIKit style?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a delegate & be informed of the progress of the load, you can use an `NSURLConnection` instead of the synchronous `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

There's an example of this in the Apple [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)

Your NSURLConnection delegate `didReceiveData:` method could append the incoming data to an `NSData` object, then you would use `UIImage imageWithData:` to create them image once everything's downloaded.

This gives you the most flexibility/control over monitoring the progress of the load; although if all you're trying to do is avoid hanging the UI while the image downloads, simply using `imageWithContentsOfFile` in a background thread may be easier.